# access sharepoint workflow information programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow

[image]

I would like to access the sharepoint "workflow information" of an item so that I can get the "status" and the "Last run" programmatically. Can anyone show me how can I get the values from these fields "Status" and "Last run"?

thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can access workflow history of an item in "Workflow History" list.

from the list you can filter tasks related to a specific item/list and workflow association.
(by using listid, itemid, workflowassociationid)

To get workflow associationid:

```
SPWorkflowAssociation assoc = myList.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("MyWFNameInEnglish",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1033));
```

The "last run" value can be obtained by getting the "Modified" date of the latest task.
The Status of the workflow can be decoded from the "Event" field.
You can find a list of the meanings for the Event values [here](http://www.spjeff.com/2010/01/29/workflow-history-event-type-numbers-decoded-2/)

PS: you can use [sharepoint manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438) to navigate through properties of a List/Web/etc. and [U2U CAML query builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx) to have a deeper look into the data inside the lists

Comment: hampidampi, thanks for your help and for sending me in the right direction, but I still don't get how to get the Status and Last Run from Workflow Information

Comment: basically you have to build a CAML query for the list related to your workflow (ie. SPList list = Web.Lists[assoc.HistoryListId]). The CAML should be something similar to: <Where><..condition..for your item ID><..order by Modified date desc..><..limit to 1 row..></Where>

Comment: the workflow that I am using is custom wf. It contains 4 tasks and the problem is that when I try to get items based on event type I cannot get any results back since all the event types contain the value comment like at the image above